# Delete orginal attachment but keep thumbnail with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a configuration setting in Paperclip to scale the orginal image down to a certain size instead of creating another version of the file?

If the user uploads a 750X750 image, I want to scale it down to 500x500. I will never use the 750x750 version so there is no reason to keep it around.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :thumb => "500x500>" }
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an easy way to override this. All you have to do is set your style to original:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :original => "500x500>" }
end
```

It won't save the original and take whatever the input image is and modify it to your specifications. Then when you want to access it, you won't need to specify a style.

```
image_tag @user.avatar
```

Instead of:

```
image_tag @user.avatar(:thumbnail)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the prettiest solution but this could work. I'm curious to know if there is a better solution.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :original => "500x500>" }
  after_create :delete_original_image

  def delete_original_image
    File.delete(self.avatar.path)
  end
end
```